# How do I simplify this equation to the form shown in the article?

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

I'm trying to obtain $(1)$ from $(2)$.

$$\frac{dr}{d \ln a} = \frac{\gamma}{H} + r \frac{d \ln g_*}{d \ln a} \tag{1}$$

$$ -HT \left(  \frac{\partial f_s}{\partial T} \right)_{E/T} = \frac{\sin^2 2\theta \hspace{1mm} \Gamma f_a}{2}\tag{2}$$

where:

- $f_a= \frac{1}{e^{E/T}+1}$
- $n_i= 2\int f_i \hspace{1mm} d^3p /(2\pi)^3$ and $r=n_s/n_a$
- $\gamma \hspace{1mm} n_a= \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{\sin^2 2\theta}{2}f_a$
- $H= \frac{d \ln a}{dt}$ is the Hubble parameter.
- $T=\frac{t^{-1/2}1.15}{k_B}$ *, better time-temperature relations might exist that I am unaware of.*
- $g_*a^3t^3= \text{constant}$

I'm told in the [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9303287) that I must do this by "*Changing the time variable from t to $a$,(...) and integrating Eq. (2) over momenta, one finds $(1)$.* "

---

**My attempt:**

Substitute $T$ in terms of $t$ and integrate both sides of the eq in terms of momentum, $d^3 p$:

$$\frac{t^{-1/2} 1.15}{k_B} \frac{\partial f_s}{\partial T} = - \frac{1}{H} \frac{\sin^2 2\theta}{2} \gamma f_a \tag{3}$$

$$2 \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{\partial f_s}{\partial T} \frac{t^{-1/2} 1.15}{k_B} = -\frac{1}{H} \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3} \sin^2 2\theta \Gamma f_a \tag{4}$$

Apply the definition of $n_i$:

$$\frac{\partial n_s}{\partial T} \frac{t^{-1/2} 1.15}{k_B} = -\frac{\gamma n_a}{H} \tag{5}$$

and move the $n_a$ to the left-side and use the definition of $r$:

$$ \frac{t^{-1/2} 1.15}{k_B} \frac{dr}{dT} = -\frac{\gamma}{H}\tag{6}$$

Rewrite $dT$ in terms of $dt$ which we use to get to $d \ln a$

$$dT= -\frac{1}{2} \frac{t^{-3/2}1.15}{k_B} dt \tag{7} $$

To have the denominator in terms of $\ln a$ I start by

$$dT =  -\frac{1}{2} \frac{t^{-3/2}1.15}{k_B} \frac{d \ln a}{H} \tag{8} $$

Further simplify this to:

$$2tH \frac{dr}{d \ln a}= \frac{\gamma}{H}$$

**This is where I get stuck, I believe I must use the equation above, which is derived from $g_* a^3 T^3 = \text{constant}$, and written in a form similar to the one below:**

$$d \ln g_* + 3 d \ln a + 3 d \ln T = 0$$

I'm not entirely sure if this is the path I should be taking.

**Could someone hint how to proceed from here, I've been trying to solve this for a long time.**

Comment: What is $f_s$? How can it disappear from calculations without a definition or relation involving it?

Comment: You wrote something different: $r=n_s/n_a$

Comment: Sorry let me edit my comment, my mistake

Comment: It is a distribution function for s,after integrating it, it gives origin to $n_s$ and through that I can divide by $n_a$ and get $r=n_s/n_a$

Comment: I think you should make clear that in the text of the question, also with related formulae

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111716/discussion-between-user7077252-and-enzotib).